# How can I match pseudoelements and elements heights with relative units?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I can´t make the following buttons identical and responsive.

I tried playing with padding and positioning but never got it to work. I also set an height to the parent element and tried to match children but nothing is working.
Another thing I find annoying  that the both pseudoelement symbols (phone and at) are not matching the font height.
Any help?
Thanks in advance.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


button {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #2973a2;
  position: relative;
  left: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.phone::before,
.email::before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2rem;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #00b1ff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.phone::before {
  content: "\260e";
}

.email::before {
  content: "\0040";
}
```

```html
<div class="btn1">
  <a href="tel:+333333333"><button class="phone">333 333 333</button></a>
  <a href="info@domain.com"><button class="email">info@domain.com</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Links cannot contain inputs/buttons and vice versa

Comment: Thanks Paulie. What a mistake. Now I changed <button> tags to <div classs="btn"> and everything is perfect

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulie_D pointed out, Links cannot contain inputs/buttons and vice versa so here is the corrected code:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


.btn{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #2973a2;
  position: relative;
  left: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.phone::before,
.email::before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2rem;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #00b1ff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.phone::before {
  content: "\260e";
}

.email::before {
  content: "\0040";
}
```

```html
<div class="btn1">
  <a href="tel:+333333333"><div class="btn phone">+ 33 333 333 333</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn1">
  <a href="info@domain.com"><div class="btn email">info@domain.com</div></a>
</div>
```